# How to install Tor to Heroku so I can use a socks5 flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, puppeteer, tor

So I'm trying to figure out how to install Tor to my Node.js app. I'm deploying this app to Heroku. I'm trying to use Puppeteer and the --proxy-server flag to create an IP rotation but I need Tor in my project to access the socks5 address. Here's my code:

```
let portList = [9050, 9052, 9053, 9054, 9055, 9056, 9057, 9058, 9059, 9060];
let spoofPort = portList[Math.floor(Math.random()*portList.length)];
puppeteerExtra.use(pluginStealth());

const browser = await puppeteerExtra.launch({ headless: true, args: [                
'--no-sandbox', 
'--disable-setuid-sandbox', 
'--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:' + spoofPort,                                      
]});

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto(`pageURL`);
```

I tried to just install a Tor Heroku buildpack (https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/todokku/heroku-buildpack-tor-proxy) but the flag still didn't work. How do I install Tor properly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/todokku/heroku-buildpack-tor-proxy just add heroku apt buildpack.

### command

To use the latest stable version of apt buildpack

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
```

- Then create a file with name `Aptfile` then write contain of the file as `tor`
- so it will install tor on heroku.
- Now heroku will generate a random  port to start our application.
- Then create a empty folder with any name to create a torrc file with our application starts
- create a bash script in the root directory.

create-torrc.sh

```
echo "HiddenServiceDir ./hidden_service" >> ./hidden_service/torrc
echo "HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:$PORT" >> ./hidden_service/torrc
tor -f ./hidden_service
```

- create a Procfile

```
web: node server.js | bash create-torrc.sh
```

Here is the example of my repository [Tor-Onion-Service-On-Heroku](https://github.com/sumithemmadi/Tor-Onion-Service-On-Heroku)